# Strange error with a templated operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, clang, sfinae

When I compile the following snippet, I get a compiler error with clang, but not with g++/MSVC:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T> struct Const { 
    explicit Const(T val) : value(val) {}
    T value;
};

template<typename T> struct Var {
    explicit Var(const std::string &n) : name(n) {}

    std::string name;
};

template<typename L, typename R> struct Greater {
    Greater(L lhs, R rhs) : left(lhs), right(rhs) {}

    L left;
    R right;
};

template<typename L>
Greater<L, Const<int> > operator > (L lhs, int rhs) { 
    return Greater<L, Const<int> >(lhs, Const<int>(rhs));
}

template<typename R>
Greater<Const<int>, R> operator > (int lhs, R rhs) { 
    return Greater<Const<int>, R>(Const<int>(lhs), rhs);
}

Var<double> d("d");

int main() {
     d > 10;
     return 0;
}
```

The error reported is the following:

```
error: overloaded 'operator>' must have at least one parameter of
      class or enumeration type
Greater<Const<int>, R> operator > (int lhs, R rhs) { 
                       ^
./val.h:31:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'operator><int>' requested here
Greater<Const<int>, R> operator > (int lhs, R rhs) { 
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

which is about the operator function that is not used. If, instead, I write 10 > d instead of d > 10, then I get the same error about the other operator > function. The above compiles fine under gcc 4.4.6 and VS2012. What is my mistake ?

Thank you.

Comment: It compiles fine with gcc 4.8.1 too: http://ideone.com/wG4Yzv (C++98 mode) and http://ideone.com/8fwOWq (C++11 mode). What's your version of clang?

Comment: @gx_ Just tried 3.1 and 3.2, both exhibit the problem.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks (too bad there's no "online Clang" (anymore)). I wonder about the very simplified example http://ideone.com/0Aooxo ? _Edit:_ oh wait, there's clang 3.0 at http://gcc.godbolt.org/ :) and my simplified example causes the same error. _Edit(2): Thanks again. Looks like a compiler bug..._

Comment: Your simplified example exhibits the same error. And removing the incorrect one causes it to succeed.

Comment: Or maybe it's actually not a bug in Clang but the other compilers are too permissive :p By the way I've read somewhere that such unconstrained templates are best avoided (especially for operator overloads)... Found: [A Modest Proposal: Fixing ADL (revision 2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2103.pdf)

Comment: @gx_ My clang version is version 3.2 (based on llvm 3.2). It is the standard clang package for ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clang is right: operator overloading requires at least one class or enum type parameter, otherwise the program is ill-formed (13.5/1). To see why this error even appears, we have to parse some more Standard legalese.

Recall the Holy Trinity of Name Lookup, Argument Deduction and Overload Resolution. The first step finds two  overloaded `operator>`. The second step deduces template arguments for each version. You might think that the second overload would fall victim to the SFINAE rule (14.8.2), so that only the first survives to the third step. However, there is no substition failure (as in e.g. a missing nested typedef), but an illegal construct (see the earlier mentioned 13.5/1). That itself renders the program ill-formed (14.3/6)

> 6 If the use of a template-argument gives rise to an ill-formed construct in the instantiation of a template specialization, the program is ill-formed.

In 14.8.3 it is mentioned that this check on the deduced arguments happens before overload resolution, so your preferred operator has no chance of being selected.

As a C++03 work-around, you could define two friend non-template `operator>` inside your `Var<T>` class template. These would be injected into the surrounding (global, in this example) namespace as non-template functions with one class type parameter, so the above error should not occur.

Comment: The OP's question uses `operator >` as the example but your answer talks about `operator <`, is this just a typo?

Comment: [DR2052](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2052) and [DR1391](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1391) now make Clang wrong in two different ways, but it looks like their resolutions haven't been implemented yet. [Clang bug 13869](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13869) is also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I don't really know why clang complains here, it looks like a bug (of the compiler). Btw, clang 3.3 also exhibits the problem.

You can suppress it using SFINAE:

```
template<typename L>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<L>::value || std::is_enum<L>::value,
                        Greater<L, Const<int>>>::type
operator > (L lhs, int rhs) { 
    return Greater<L, Const<int> >(lhs, Const<int>(rhs));
}

template<typename R>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<R>::value || std::is_enum<R>::value,
                        Greater<Const<int>,R>>::type
operator > (int lhs, R rhs) { 
    return Greater<Const<int>, R>(Const<int>(lhs), rhs);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only use C++03. Correct if I'm wrong, but std::enable_if, std::is_class etc are C++11 constructs so I cannot use them

Comment: @John enable_if is a few lines of code that you can write yourself, but is_class requires compiler support, so you can't use this without c++11

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in g++ and VS to me. In your example, your type `R` is `int` (because the right-hand operand is `int`). This then makes the signature of the function `Greater<Const<int>, R> operator > (int lhs, int rhs)` *which is the same (parameter) signature as the builtin `operator<` for ints*. Note that it has to consider both templates (and attempt to deduce types separately for each) when deciding which `operator>` to use: It can't just look at one of them and decide to ignore the other one.

Comment: When considering both templates, an invalid template instantiation should be ignored or is it an error ?

Comment: @John no, only substitution failures are not errors (sfinae), any other illegal construct during argument deduction are hard errors. See my answer for more details.