# Is this code valid? Works with gcc, don't work with clang

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang, clang++

The following minimal code compiles on g++, but won't compile on clang++:

```
template<class T>
T operator*(float a, const T& b)
{
    return b * a;
}

struct A{
    A operator*(float b) const
    {
        A a;
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    2.0f * a;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp 
test.cpp:2:3: error: overloaded 'operator*' must have at least one parameter of
      class or enumeration type
T operator*(float a, const T& b)
  ^
test.cpp:4:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'operator*<float>' requested here
        return b * a;
                 ^
test.cpp:18:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'operator*<A>' requested here
    2.0f * a;
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Clang version 3.5. Is this code valid? Is there a bug on Clang?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596412/strange-error-with-a-templated-operator-overload May help?

Comment: I think @Namfuak has found a duplicate: The expression `b * a` tries to instantiate the operator function template, which leads to `T` being deduced as `float`, and the produced specialization (an operator function) is ill-formed, since it has no parameter of class/enumeration type or reference thereof. This seems to be no substitution failure, i.e. a hard error. See [over.oper]/1 and /6.

Comment: I was trying to minimise your code further and removed `A::operator*`... but noticed that this prevented GCC from compiling the code. Interesting...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The error message is interesting: It hints at substitution, which should not be the issue. That there's no valid conversion from `A` to `float` is an overload resolution issue (viable overloads are selected after template instantiation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2.0f * a;` instantiates `::operator*<A>`. Within that function, we have the expression `b * a`, which, if you look at the (simplified) types, is `A * float`. At this point, the compiler needs to make a choice. Should that `*` be the global function `::operator*<float>` (because the right hand argument is `float`), or should it be `A::operator*`? To us humans, it's clear it should be `A::operator*`, but from the compiler's perspective it's not immediately clear.

So what does the compiler do? It first tries to find all the `operator*` functions that *could* be used (after which, it tries to determine exactly which one to use). One of those `operator*` functions that *could* be used is `::operator*<float>`. But wait, what is `::operator*<float>`? It's `float *(float, const float&)`! And we can't do that! You can't overload operators for primitive types (imagine the chaos if you overloaded `int +(int, int)` so you make `1 + 2` do something totally different from what everyone expected it to do).

At this point, the program is ill-formed. The mere fact that the compiler even tries to instantiate `::operator*<float>` invalidates the program as a whole. So what can we do? Tell the compiler exactly what to do:

```
template<class T>
T operator*(float a, const T& b)
{
    // This prevents the compiler from instantiating ::operator*<float>
    return b.operator*(a);

    // The above is meant to illustrate how the fix needs to work: it needs
    // to avoid instantiating ::operator*<float>. Other methods can be used
    // (like SFINAE) that might be more elegant (check out Walter's answer
    // in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596809/1287251), but
    // in the end any solution used must avoid ::operator*<float>.
}

struct A{
    A operator*(float b) const
    {
        A a;
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    2.0f * a;
}
```

In short, to answer the question: no, the code is not valid. You must prevent the compiler from trying to instantiate `::operator*<float>`.

[This is explained by @dyp in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566388/is-this-code-valid-works-with-gcc-dont-work-with-clang/26568072#comment41752289_26566388) and [by @TemplateRex in the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600649/1287251). However, I had to read their responses several times before I understood what they meant. I've tried to simplify things in this answer. If I can improve it, please let me know!